# Opening a new tab from the context menu in Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

After reading [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs) two [sites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu) , I cannot get a piece of JS code to run from a context menu.

index.js:

```
var self = require('sdk/self');
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
var uri = "";
var script = 'self.on("click", function (node, data) {' +
                'var uri = "http://test.net/?blee=" + node.href + "blue=true";' +
                'console.log(uri);'+
                'tabs.open(uri);'+
                '});';
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
    label: "label",
    context: contextMenu.SelectorContext("a[href]"),
    contentScript: script,
    onMessage: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});`
```

That's the entire extension right there and what's strange is that it outputs the `var uri` to the console, but it fails at `tabs.open(uri)`. Should `tabs.open` be inside a function or something instead of this awkward script?

I'm attempting to write my chrome extension for firefox to do the exact same thing. Here's the code from the chrome extension

main.js:

```
  runFunction= function(word){
  var query = word.linkUrl;
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://test.net/?blee=" + query + "&blue=True"});
   };

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Title!",
  contexts:["link"],
  onclick: runFunction
});
```

Comment: does firefox web extensions - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API support enough of the chrome web extension API for you to use the chrome extension with virtually no modification? To be honest I'm not sure if firefox web extensions are available in release versions of firefox yet, but it's just a thought

Comment: @JaromandaX, I did notice that the WebExtensions API is coming out soon, but I did not read into it very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the contextMenu script you `self.postMessage` the uri

Then open the tab in the menuItem `onMessage` function

```
var self = require('sdk/self');
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
var uri = "";
var script = 'self.on("click", function (node, data) {' +
                'var uri = "http://test.net/?blee=" + node.href + "blue=true";' +
                'console.log(uri);'+
                'self.postMessage(uri);'+
                '});';
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
    label: "label",
    context: contextMenu.SelectorContext("a[href]"),
    contentScript: script,
    onMessage: function (data) {
        tabs.open(data);
    }
});
```

If the script for the context menus is getting cumbersome, put it in a file in the `data` folder of your extension - it has to be `data` folder

For example if it's named `data/contextScript.js`, then, instead of

```
contentScript: script,
```

use

```
contentScriptFile: './contextScript.js',
```

note the **lack** of `data` in the path

That syntax,

```
contentScriptFile: './filename.js'
```

is a shortcut for

```
contentScriptFile: self.data.url("filename.js")
```

Which is the syntax for earlier versions of jpm SDK